# How to build tensorflow benchmark tool

Tags: tensorflow, build, bazel

Following https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/benchmark

`bazel build -c opt --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool --cpu=armeabi-v7a --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain --config monolithic tensorflow/tools/benchmark:benchmark_model`

I get

```
WARNING: The following rc files are no longer being read, please transfer their contents or import their path into one of the standard rc files:
/Users/user/external_projects/tensorflow/tools/bazel.rc
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=1 --terminal_columns=176
ERROR: Config value monolithic is not defined in any .rc file
```

How to fix it?

`bazel version`

```
WARNING: The following rc files are no longer being read, please transfer their contents or import their path into one of the standard rc files:
/Users/user/external_projects/tensorflow/tools/bazel.rc
Build label: 0.23.1
Build target: bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Mon Mar 4 10:40:32 2019 (1551696032)
Build timestamp: 1551696032
Build timestamp as int: 1551696032
```

**Update:**

For fresh tensorflow master I get:

```
INFO: Analysed target //tensorflow/tools/benchmark:benchmark_model (71 packages loaded, 4664 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_user/144c1461f36cde95de1693452c235294/external/com_google_absl/absl/types/BUILD.bazel:178:1: C++ compilation of rule '@com_google_absl//absl/types:bad_optional_access' failed (Exit 1)
clang: error: unknown argument: '-m<platform_for_version_min>-version-min=10.14'
Target //tensorflow/tools/benchmark:benchmark_model failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 98.302s, Critical Path: 18.67s
INFO: 399 processes: 399 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

**Update 2:**

On Ubuntu 16 and fresh tensorflow master:

`bazel version`

```
INFO: Invocation ID: 34e40dab-96b2-45ef-b549-dab45a2738bc
Build label: 0.22.0
Build target: bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Mon Jan 28 12:58:08 2019 (1548680288)
Build timestamp: 1548680288
Build timestamp as int: 1548680288
```

Output:

```
WARNING: /data/user_data/external_projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1794:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib_lite: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime:server_lib.h' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there
INFO: Analysed target //tensorflow/tools/benchmark:benchmark_model (72 packages loaded, 4809 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
INFO: From Compiling external/snappy/snappy-sinksource.cc [for host]:
cc1plus: warning: command line option '-Wno-implicit-function-declaration' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
INFO: From Compiling external/snappy/snappy-stubs-internal.cc [for host]:
cc1plus: warning: command line option '-Wno-implicit-function-declaration' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
INFO: From Compiling external/snappy/snappy.cc [for host]:
cc1plus: warning: command line option '-Wno-implicit-function-declaration' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
ERROR: /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/b4774fbdb8542988b4e302c9e073f145/external/com_google_absl/absl/container/BUILD.bazel:529:1: C++ compilation of rule '@com_google_absl//absl/container:raw_hash_set' failed (Exit 1)
Target //tensorflow/tools/benchmark:benchmark_model failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 59.522s, Critical Path: 11.24s
INFO: 456 processes: 456 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the NDK are you using? I used the following command line and it worked:

```
$ bazel build -c opt \
  --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool \ 
  --cpu=armeabi-v7a \
  --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain \
  --config monolithic \
  --cxxopt=-std=c++11 \
  tensorflow/tools/benchmark:benchmark_model
```

This is with Bazel 0.23.2 and NDK r17c on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/7bd86377dedaf459d22b68363a0a2d4580180379.